# In Flex/AS3, how do I get a class definition of an embedded asset with getDefinitionByName

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, embed

I have a class with many embedded assets.

Within the class, I would like to get the class definition of an asset by name.  I have tried using getDefinitionByName(), and also ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.getDefinition() but neither work.

Example:

```
public class MyClass
{
  [Embed(source="images/image1.png")] private static var Image1Class:Class;
  [Embed(source="images/image2.png")] private static var Image2Class:Class;
  [Embed(source="images/image3.png")] private static var Image3Class:Class;

  private var _image:Bitmap;

  public function MyClass(name:String)
  {
    var ClassDef:Class = getDefinitionByName(name) as Class;  //<<-- Fails
    _image = new ClassDef() as Bitmap;    
  }
}

var cls:MyClass = new MyClass("Image1Class");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question, but it may solve your problem.  I believe doing something like this should work:

```
public class MyClass
{
  [Embed(source="images/image1.png")] private static var Image1Class:Class;
  [Embed(source="images/image2.png")] private static var Image2Class:Class;
  [Embed(source="images/image3.png")] private static var Image3Class:Class;

  private var _image:Bitmap;

  public function MyClass(name:String)
  {
    _image = new this[name]() as Bitmap;    
  }
}

var cls:MyClass = new MyClass("Image1Class");
```

I'm having a tough time remembering if bracket notation works on sealed classes.  If it doesn't, a simple solution is to mark the class as dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your method does not work is because "Image1Class" is a *variable* name, not the actual *Class name*.

You can get the class name like this

```
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;
trace(getQualifiedClassName(Image1Class));
```

Which as you may see, means your class name (the one that should be passed into the function) is something like `MyClass_Image1Class`.

Comment: But, I would still recommend one of the above methods, as `getDefinitionByName()` would only be necessary if you are accessing those images _outside_ of your current class.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use any fancy getDefinitionByName() methods, simply refer to it dynamically. In your case, replace the 'Fails' line with:

```
var classDef:Class = MyClass[name] as Class;
```

And that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much!  I just spent almost 5 hours trying to get the POS getDefinitionByName to work with the getQualifiedClassName that I was ready to throw stuff!!  My final working code looks like this and even gets the string name from an array.

CreatureParam is a 2 dimentional array of strings;

Type is an integer that is sent to flash by HTML tag  which is turn comes from a MYSQL database via PHP.

Mark1_cb is a combobox that is on the stage and has an instance name. It's output is also an integer.

So this code directly below imports the class "BirdBodyColor_mc" from an external swf "ArtLibrary.swf".  BirdBodyColor_mc is a movieclip created from a png image.  Note you must double click on the movieclip in the ArtLibrary.fla and insert a second key frame.  Movieclips apparently need two frames or flash tries to import it as a sprite and causes a type mismatch.

[Embed(source="ArtLibrary.swf", symbol="BirdBodyColor_mc")]
var BirdBodyColor_mc:Class;

Normally I would put an instance of this movieclip class on the stage by using this code.

myMC:MovieClip = new BirdBodyColor_mc();
addChild(myMC);

var Definition:Class = this["BirdBodyColor_mc"] as Class;
var Mark1:MovieClip = new Definition();

But I need to do this using a string value looked up in my array.  So here is the code for that.

var Definition:Class = this[CreatureParam[Type][Mark1_cb + 2]] as Class;
var Mark1:MovieClip = new Definition();